# JPA: How can I read particular fields of an Entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring JPA ( Hibernate ) and have bunch of entities which are mapped onto tables.
When I use an entity to write I need many fields in it (see an example below). But when I read, I wanna sometimes read only particular fields like first/last name. How can I perform it using Spring data JPA ? ( because due to `CrudRepository` nature it returns the whole entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID_PERSON"))
public class Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
     
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
     
    @Column(name="MIDDLE_NAME", length = 50)
    private String middleName;
     
    @Column(name="BIRTHDAY", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthday;
     
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SEX")
    private Sex sex;
 
    public Person() {
        super();
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
    public Sex getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
    public void setSex(Sex sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various possibilities.

With Spring Data JPA you can use projection (that's the name when you only select certain fields/columns of an entity/table).

You can return List of Object[] or a DTO or an Interface.

For example with interface it looks like this:

```
interface NamesOnly {

  String getFirstname();
  String getLastname();
}

interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {
   Collection<NamesOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

As you can see the return value most not be of type Person.

Please check out the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Thank you! Is it applicable to CrudRepository?

Comment: Sure CrudRepository is a subtype of Repository

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with a similar issue and I resorted to this:

Let's say you have your entity `FooEntity` related to repository `FooRepository`

To only get certain fields, let's say `firstName` and `lastName` using `key` I had to create a custom query in the `FooRepository`

In this manner

```
@Query("select new FooEntity(f.firstName, f.lastName) from FooEntity f where f.key = :key")
    Optional<FooEntity> findCustomByKey(@Param("key") BigInteger key);
```

You also have to ensure that the `FooEntity` has the constructor accepting the values that you only want to be set or returned in this manner:

```
  public FooEntity(String firstName, String lastName){

      // Ensure the constructor is not called with null values

       notNull(firstName, "Method called with null parameter (firstName)");
       notNull(lastName, "Method called with null parameter (lastName)");
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

Please the full code below:

```
public class FooEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "key")
    private BigInteger key;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "hash")
    private String hash;
    
    public FooEntity(String firstName, String lastName){

      // Ensure the constructor is not called with null values

       notNull(firstName, "Method called with null parameter (firstName)");
       notNull(lastName, "Method called with null parameter (lastName)");
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    // Getters and Setters
    
 }
```

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooEntity, BigInteger>{

    @Query("select new FooEntity(f.firstName, f.lastName) from FooEntity f where f.key = :key")
    Optional<FooEntity> findCustomById(@Param("key") BigInteger key); // This one only returns two set fields firstName and LastName and the rest as nulls

    Optional<FooEntity> findById(BigInteger key) // This one returns all the fields
}
```